# how many instances of SqlConnection should I use

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sqlconnection

Background: 
I have an application that I have nicely separated my interface logic from my middle tier logic which handles the queries to the database. I do a lot of custom sorting and narrowing so I'm not using many SqlDataSources and instead calling a lot of stored procedures with SqlCommands.

I am using Forms Authentication to create protected sub-directories. In the web.config files in the protected directories I have more connection strings that link to users with higher privileged roles.

Question: 
Should I share a SqlConnection object in my middle tier to cut out repetitive code, or should I create a new instance for each operation? A shared SqlConnection I could re-instantiate if I need to change connection strings to get access to protected stored procedures. Is there a best practice here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't worry about sharing to conserve resources.  .NET will manage this for you, it does connection pooling by default.  Write the code to be clear and understandable and let .NET take care of these details.

Answer (score 11):

Create as many SqlConnections as you need, as shortly lived as possible, through the using statement:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(...)) {
  connection.Open();
  ...
}
```

Sql connections are taken from a connection pool, which will automatically manage contention for you.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(VS.80).aspx

Comment: +1 for the answer.  The "using" syntax is definitely the way to go (I think it can be used for file/stream access also).

Comment: Sure it can, for any disposable resource (classes implementing IDisposable)

Answer (score 2):

Create a new one (and dispose properly) and utilize [connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx).